# command failing in login code in C# on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication

I am making a website using ASP.NET framework.
My code for login page is as below, it is very simple since I'm trying to see step by step where it is going wrong. The C# code is:

```
 protected void userLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string encoded_pass = encrypt_pass(Password.Text);
     SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Khulna_website"].ConnectionString);
     connection.Open();
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("Select * from users where user_email= @email and user_password = @password"))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Email.Text);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", encoded_pass);

             try
             {
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                 //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                 //da.Fill(dt);
                 ////Session["User"] = dt.Rows[0]["user_email"];
                 //Session["User_name"] = dt.Rows[0]["user_f_name"];
                 //loginlabel.Text = "Welcome, " + Session["User_name"];
             }
             catch
             {
                 loginlabel.Text = "login error";
             }
     }
     connection.Close();
 }
```

Now every time I enter an email and password it always gives "login errorr".. Why the command is not executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have declared the connection but haven't assigned it to the SqlCommand

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("Select * from users where user_email= @email and user_password = @password",connection))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Email.Text);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", encoded_pass);
```

Note i added the connection variable in the cmd declaration.
In future you may also like catching your errors in development:

```
catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 loginlabel.Text = "login error: "+ ex.Message;
             }
```

This will help you know what is going wrong.

Comment: Yes, it worked! I didn't even notice it.  Thanks for helping!! :D

Comment: @JigJagJoe it's definitely 1 of the common errors you will come across and not easy to resolve unless you debug or return the exception being thrown

Comment: "Return the exception been thrown"? That's a good idea. How to do that?

Comment: As in the second part of my answer. This will give you the details of the exception right on the loginlabel.

Comment: Thanks.. it's been really helpful

Comment: Cool... really nice to know i have been of assistance. Cheers!